# GCP OS Login creates user_domain account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am testing OS login and created a instance with metadata "enable-oslogin=TRUE". I then added OS Login role to my account(user@mydomainname.com). When I tried:

```
user@original_host$ gcloud compute ssh my_instance --project my_project --zone my_zone
```

GCP allowed me login, but as user user_mydomainname instead of my original account "user"

When I tried:

`user@original_host$ ssh my_instance, it denied my login`.

When I tried:

```
user@original_host$ ssh user_mydomainname@my_instance, it allowed me login, but as user_mydomainname of course.
```

I read a bunch of OS login documents from Google and could not figure out the reason. IN one doc: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#login_messages

At the `Expected login behaviors` section, it reads "If a username is not set by a G Suite administrator, OS Login generates a default Linux username by combining the username and domain from the email associated with the user's Google profile. This naming convention ensures uniqueness. For example, if the user email associated with the Google profile is user@example.com, then their generated username is user_example_com."

This looks like what I am getting, but I had set OS login role to my account.

I was expecting with the OS login role setup, I could login to the instance as my original account: user

Did I miss anything here or this is indeed the expected behavior? Is is possible to get my account "user" to use OS Login w/o getting user_mydomainname?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: What is the relationship (if any) between the account `user@mydomainname.com` and the GCP project hosting the compute engine?  For example, is this account managed by GSuite or Cloud Identity Manager which then is the organizations for the project?  What, if any, IAM permissions for this user were granted to the Compute Engine with respect to OS Login?

Answer (score 4):

At first, I've tried to check it OS Login feature on my test VM by following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access):

1. create VM instance:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create os-login-instance-1 --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --zone=europe-west3-a              
   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/os-login-instance-1].
   NAME                 ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
   os-login-instance-1  europe-west3-a  n1-standard-1               10.156.15.226  35.XXX.236.XXX  RUNNING
   ```
2. enable OS Login feature for VM:

   ```
   $ cloud compute instances add-metadata os-login-instance-1 --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE --zone=europe-west3-a              
   Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/os-login-instance-1].
   ```
3. add role `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` for username@domain.com to make it able to use `sudo` command:

   ```
   $ gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding test-prj \
    --member='user:username@domain.com' \
    --role='roles/compute.osAdminLogin'
   Updated IAM policy for project [test-prj].
   ```

you can use `roles/compute.osLogin` for non-root access.

4. create SSH keys to connect:

   ```
   $ ssh-keygen
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   ```
5. upload SSH key to the project:

   ```
   gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file .ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```
6. connect to your instance:

   ```
   $ ssh username_domain_com@35.242.236.114                          

   Linux os-login-instance-1 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64

   The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

   Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
   permitted by applicable law.
   Creating directory '/home/username_domain_com'.
   username_domain_com@os-login-instance-1:~$ 

   $ gcloud compute ssh os-login-instance-1
   Linux os-login-instance-1 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64

   The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

   Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
   permitted by applicable law.
   Last login: Mon Feb 17 12:32:56 2020 from 104.132.189.65
   username_domain_com@os-login-instance-1:~$ whoami
   username_domain_com
   ```

or you can use FQDN name (should be resolved) instead of IP.

As we expected full e-mail address was transformed and all dots and special characters was replaced by an underscore accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#login_messages):

> If a username is not set by a G Suite administrator, OS Login
>   generates a default Linux username by combining the username and
>   domain from the email associated with the user's Google profile. This
>   naming convention ensures uniqueness. For example, if the user email
>   associated with the Google profile is `user@example.com`, then their
>   generated username is `user_example_com`.

```
username@domain.com becomes -> username_domain_com
```

and I was able to connect to VM, but with `username_domain_com` name.

**Let's have a look at the documentation how to change** `username_domain_com` **into** `username` in the same [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#login_messages):

> **G Suite organizations can optionally change their default to remove
>   the domain suffix for newly generated usernames.** For example, if the
>   user email associated with the Google profile is `user@example.com`,
>   then their generated username is `user`. For more information, see
>   [Managing the OS Login API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#manage-oslogin-api).

and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/692) you can find more details why it works in that way:

> OS Login ties your Linux user account to your Google identity so that
>   you have a consistent username, UID, and other posix information, in
>   every VM you log into. This allows the VM to authorize your login
>   using IAM permissions so that you can easily revoke access. **The
>   posix information is immutable for consumer identities (non-G Suite
>   users)**. This prevents a bad actor from setting information in a
>   malicious way that a project owner cannot manage. In order to prevent
>   uniqueness conflicts across different organizations (`user@gmail.com`
>   and `user@example.com`) the domain name is included by default.

*So, you can use `username` instead of `username_domain.com` for your G Suite organization, and you can't if you're an individual customer*.

Answer (score 1):

Settings such as the username are taken from the Directory API. The relevant documentation page is here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#modify-users

For further details, you likely want to review the documentation on the Directory API linked there.

Comment: If you enabled OS Login and logged in before changing the G Suite setting mentioned in Serhii's answer, you are stuck with a POSIX username that includes the domain. This API call is currently the ONLY way to modify your POSIX username for OS Login.